# Nesting simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Try to wright a xml with SimpleXmL. Need to nest some of the tags

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><orders></orders>');
        $orderlist = $xml->addChild('order');
        $orderlist->addAttribute('shipdate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $orderlist = $xml->addChild('delivery');
        $orderlist->addAttribute('weight', '0');
```

This will output this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <orders>
        <order shipdate="2017-10-11 13:44:12" />
        <delivery weight="0" />
    <order/>
    </orders>
```

But need the  tag not to close before the  tag. 
Want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
  <order shipdate="2016-07-14T14:41:30">
    <delivery weight="0" />
  </order>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><orders></orders>');
        $orderlist = $xml->addChild('order');
        $orderlist->addAttribute('shipdate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $delivery = $orderlist->addChild('delivery');
        $delivery->addAttribute('weight', '0');
```

This will add the `<delivery>` tag inside `<order>` tag. And provide the output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<orders>
    <order shipdate="2017-10-11 22:28:13">
        <delivery weight="0"/>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add child to `$orderlist`, then write it properly:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><orders></orders>');
// add child to root node `orders`
$orderlist = $xml->addChild('order');
$orderlist->addAttribute('shipdate', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

// add child to newly created `order` node
$delivery = $orderlist->addChild('delivery');
$delivery->addAttribute('weight', '0');

echo $xml->asXML();
```